# Javascript function work on windows but not white space creates on mac

Tags: javascript

I have a website and im trying to get my javascript function to NOT create a white space on mac which the white space increases with EVERY refresh.

First, I created what i want in svg, then i trigger/control it with javascript. Then I have a javascript function that detects if it's not windows. Can i clear the white space, have it on both mac and windows, and still work?

I'm not posting the code that is causing the white space because I don't know what is causing it.

Here's the detection code:

```
(function() {
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS X/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        ) {
    isApple = true;
    if (confirm("Because this is a Apple device, It is not reccommended for you to view this site on this device. You will now be transferred to Google.com. I am working on a fix. Thank you for your patience.")){
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
    }else{
    alert("It is NOT recommended that you view this site at this time. I am working on a fix. Please leave this site now.")}
};
    }
)();
```

I would also like to cancel the fade function whenever the isApple true. Here's the fade code:

```
$(document).ready(function fade(){
  window.onload = (function(){
$("#circ1").fadeIn();
$("#circ2").fadeIn("slow");
$("#circ3").fadeIn(800);
$("#circ4").fadeIn(900);
$("#circ5").fadeIn(1000);
$("#circ6").fadeIn(1100);
$("#circ7").fadeIn(1200);
$("#circ8").fadeIn(1250);
$("#circ9").fadeIn(1300);
$("#circ10").fadeIn(1350);
$("#circ11").fadeIn(1400);
$("#circ12").fadeIn(1450);
$("#circ13").fadeIn(1500);
$("#circ14").fadeIn(1550);
$("#circ15").fadeIn(1600);

$("#circ1").fadeOut();
$("#circ2").fadeOut("slow");
$("#circ3").fadeOut(800);
$("#circ4").fadeOut(900);
$("#circ5").fadeOut(1000);
$("#circ6").fadeOut(1100);
$("#circ7").fadeOut(1200);
$("#circ8").fadeOut(1250);
$("#circ9").fadeOut(1300);
$("#circ10").fadeOut(1350);
$("#circ11").fadeOut(1400);
$("#circ12").fadeOut(1450);
$("#circ13").fadeOut(1500);
$("#circ14").fadeOut(1550);
$("#circ15").fadeOut(1600);
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the posted code have anything to do with whitespace?

Comment: I'm running Chrome on a Mac, my user agent doesn't match any of those things.

Comment: I just checked Safari on my Mac, it also doesn't match. What is webOS X?

Comment: Yeah, webOSX will never match. I gave details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match something that would actually be in a max user agent string (you could see yours by doing a console.log on navigator.userAgent. Use either "Mac OS X" or "Macintosh". A sample user string `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function() 
    {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            ) 
      {
        isApple = true;
        if (confirm("Because this is a Apple device, It is not reccommended for you to view this site on this device. You will now be transferred to Google.com. I am working on a fix. Thank you for your patience.")){
          window.location = "https://www.google.com";
          }else{
          alert("It is NOT recommended that you view this site at this time. I am working on a fix. Please leave this site now.")}
      }else{
       loadFade();
      } 
    })();

    function loadFade(){
        $("#circ1").fadeIn();
        $("#circ2").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#circ3").fadeIn(800);
        $("#circ4").fadeIn(900);
        $("#circ5").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#circ6").fadeIn(1100);
        $("#circ7").fadeIn(1200);
        $("#circ8").fadeIn(1250);
        $("#circ9").fadeIn(1300);
        $("#circ10").fadeIn(1350);
        $("#circ11").fadeIn(1400);
        $("#circ12").fadeIn(1450);
        $("#circ13").fadeIn(1500);
        $("#circ14").fadeIn(1550);
        $("#circ15").fadeIn(1600);

        $("#circ1").fadeOut();
        $("#circ2").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#circ3").fadeOut(800);
        $("#circ4").fadeOut(900);
        $("#circ5").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#circ6").fadeOut(1100);
        $("#circ7").fadeOut(1200);
        $("#circ8").fadeOut(1250);
        $("#circ9").fadeOut(1300);
        $("#circ10").fadeOut(1350);
        $("#circ11").fadeOut(1400);
        $("#circ12").fadeOut(1450);
        $("#circ13").fadeOut(1500);
        $("#circ14").fadeOut(1550);
        $("#circ15").fadeOut(1600);

    };
});
```

For the whitespace, it's down to the svg filling the screen. If you want to keep it on the left and keep the content as if it's not there just add:

```
<style type="text/css">
svg { position: absolute;}
</style>
```

To the header section of the page, or you can instead assign it width and height, in the CSS for the element or directly in the svg tag `<svg width="400" height="200" >` for instance and everything will align under it properly.

Comment: Right. I don't have a check for windows because it works fine there. About the white space, i don't have code that's causing that because I don't know what is causing the white space. I just need some code that will get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried updating the code that sniffs for the mac as I showed above to eliminate that as causing the issue? The white-space could have to do with the bad code, but that's impossible to say without seeing your html (could be line-break types or many other things).

Comment: Yes. Now it behaves just as it does with the ipod/iphone/ipad. It loads the warnings, but still loads the fade if you hit cancel and ok. Can we disable the fade function when isApple is true?

Comment: Updated in my answer.

Comment: Now, the fade isn't loading at all. It's almost like the isApple detection isn't working. I'm not getting the warnings.

Comment: Sorry, didn't name the function correctly, updated.

Comment: still not working. look at it josh20.6te.net

Comment: Ah, the else was in the wrong place, that's fixed, but you'll need to move that code to the onready function above as well or you'll get an undefined error. I combined them and tested, and it seems to work.

Comment: So, put this along with the fade function? I don't understand. Can you show me? Also, what about the white space? Does this fix it?

Comment: Yeah, they should all be done in document on ready. I combined them above, and this should work. I'd make your next project writing an if loop to create all those fadeIn/fadeOut elements if I were you!

Comment: Sweet! It works. Still some white space left on apple devices, but I guess I can live with that. That's exactly what I want to do! I just wanted everything else to work properly first.

Comment: Sweet, if you would accept my answer that would be great. I'll see if I can work out the whitespace on my mac later. Are you seeing it in the dialogue boxes or where?

Comment: I did. I really appreciate all your help. The white space appears at the very top where the fade goes and before the hit counter.

Comment: Oh, that's the svg! I added comments in my answer.

Comment: Where would the change go? What part in the svg?

Comment: Clarified in the answer. You can do it through CSS or the svg tag.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But could you look at my code and note any syntax errors? I've already corrected some but this guy is being a jerk about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547153/getting-fade-in-out-into-a-continual-loop

Comment: @Josh - that guy being a jerk about it was helping you out by pointing out numerous syntax errors in your site, as well as provided a long list of corrections you should make.   Some people might just say thank you...

Comment: What Charlie said. I think if you plan on continuing to develop sites it would be really good to start with the basics, and then you will be able to recognize the errors yourself, which will be a lot more useful. I started out copying and pasting code, but when I started to understand the js I was implementing it was a great feeling. Start out with adding developer tools to whichever browser you use. Here are some tutorials: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/