# Getting fade in/out into a continual loop

Tags: javascript

I have a website and I got help from spacebean to get this far. Now, I would like help in getting the fade in/out part of the following code into a continual loop and I don't know how to go about it. I also would like it if the white space that is currently appearing on Macs/iPod/iPhone/iPad to go away. It appears at the very top before the hit counter.Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function() 
{
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        ) 
  {
    isApple = true;
    if (confirm("Because this is a Apple device, It is not reccommended for you to view this site on this device. You will now be transferred to Google.com. I am working on a fix. Thank you for your patience.")){
      window.location = "https://www.google.com";
      }else{
      alert("It is NOT recommended that you view this site at this time. I am working on a fix. Please leave this site now.")}
  }else{
   loadFade();
  } 
})();

function loadFade(){
    $("#circ1").fadeIn();
    $("#circ2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#circ3").fadeIn(800);
    $("#circ4").fadeIn(900);
    $("#circ5").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#circ6").fadeIn(1100);
    $("#circ7").fadeIn(1200);
    $("#circ8").fadeIn(1250);
    $("#circ9").fadeIn(1300);
    $("#circ10").fadeIn(1350);
    $("#circ11").fadeIn(1400);
    $("#circ12").fadeIn(1450);
    $("#circ13").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#circ14").fadeIn(1550);
    $("#circ15").fadeIn(1600);

    $("#circ1").fadeOut();
    $("#circ2").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#circ3").fadeOut(800);
    $("#circ4").fadeOut(900);
    $("#circ5").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#circ6").fadeOut(1100);
    $("#circ7").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#circ8").fadeOut(1250);
    $("#circ9").fadeOut(1300);
    $("#circ10").fadeOut(1350);
    $("#circ11").fadeOut(1400);
    $("#circ12").fadeOut(1450);
    $("#circ13").fadeOut(1500);
    $("#circ14").fadeOut(1550);
    $("#circ15").fadeOut(1600);

    };
});
```

Comment: And what do you expect it will be doing? and what is wrong now?

Comment: Right now, the only thing that is wrong is the white space appearing. The loop will just be an enhancement.

Comment: I don't think you provided the relevant code for your white space.

Comment: Out of curiosity...  why the Apple hate?   The site works just fine on an Apple device, as I just tested it on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: Also...  the `<center>` tag was deprecated years ago, and shouldn't be used.  I noticed it in your source code.

Comment: I put it there because I thought that's what's creating the white space. Now I know it's because of the svg in there. If I put the fade in the apple stuff again, then it's not centered.

Comment: @Josh - if you read my answer below, you will see that your site is riddled with syntax errors throughout the page.   I would concentrate on cleaning up all the code before worrying about whitespace, as starting with a VALID page will greatly reduce your troubleshooting efforts.  As it is, the invalid syntax on the page may be the root cause of your problems, as not all browsers will be "nice" to you and work around your coding mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the callback for the last item that fades out to call the function again.

```
$("#circ15").fadeOut(1600, function () {
    loadFade();
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/SD4G3/

Answer (score 1):

For Getting fade in/out into a continual loop, Try calling this function :

```
function loadFade() {       
        for(var i=1; i<=15; i++) 
           $("#circ"+i).fadeToggle(loadFade); 
}
```

Beware... It just goes in an infinite loop. And here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ULBB9/).

Answer (score 1):

The site is riddled with syntax problems.

This code here:

```
<!-- End 1FreeCounter.com code -->
</center>

</center><font color="#000000"><BR>
```

You can see that you are closing the center tag twice in a row.   This in invalid on your page.

In that same section, the next couple lines down...

```
<!-- End 1FreeCounter.com code -->
</center>

</center><font color="#000000"><BR>
</body>
</html>
<img id="img0" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:1000; visibility:hidden;" src="happy.gif" />
```

You are closing your body and html tags (presumably from copy / pasting content from other websites).  The body and html tags should be the last two things on your page, not in the middle of the page.

Again, farther down, this code:

```
<h3><b><center><br>Hello. This is Josh's Website.</b></h3>
```

You have h3 -> b -> center, but you are only closing b -> h3.   You did not close the center tag, also creating invalid syntax.

Then down around line 134, you have this:

```
</head>
<body>
```

A random closing of the head tag in the middle of your website, and then a body tag (even though we are well in to the body).

And the errors continue, and continue, and continue...

I **HIGHLY** recommend you learn some basic HTML, and not copy / paste things you find on other websites in to your own site, without first learning these basics.    It's amazing that your page loads at all...

Comment: The happy.gif part was for a mouse trail that I took out a while ago and just forgot to take it out. The other stuff I also didn't see a problem with it being there and it made it work. If you would like, change everything you noted to make it proper and if it works, great. I will change it.

Comment: @Josh - No, I would not like to change all your coding mistakes.   As mentioned before, I **HIGHLY** recommend you learn some basic HTML.  If you do not understand why all your code is incorrect, and don't feel that you should take the time to correct those mistakes, you shouldn't be creating webpages.   Take some pride in your work, and clean up your code.  It's awful.

Comment: I did. Like I said, I simply didn't notice every single little mistake because I created my site around 2-3 am about 3 days ago. I will look over it more and make more changes as I see them to try to make it proper. Also, could you tell me what you are using to see these problems?

Comment: @Josh - I just opened your page, and selected View Source.   Honestly, the errors are extremely obvious if you know some basic HTML rules.   For example, you should only have one `HTML` and one `BODY` tag on the page.  Ever.  Period.   This is the most basic of HTML rules.   And you have several `HTML` and `BODY` tags on the page.   Aside from taking the time to learn these basic rules, I suggest using this site:  http://www.onlinewebcheck.com/   to offer some suggestions to fix all of your syntax.   It's not perfect, but will give you a good starting point.